# Debugging Angular Javascript code, Not showing scope in the Model option of batarang debugger

Tags: angularjs, debugging

I can't get the scope of the angularjs in batarang. i spent a lot time on debugging angularjs but i am not able to get the scope. here is the html code

```
    <div data-ng-controller="RegisterCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="error in registerError">
        <div class="alert alert-danger animated fadeIn">{{error.msg}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger animated fadeIn" ng-show="usernameError">{{usernameError}}</div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger animated fadeIn" ng-show="emailError">{{emailError}}</div>

    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form ng-submit="register()" class="signup form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-md-4 control-label">Repeat Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="confirmPassword" type="password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.confirmPassword"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>&nbsp;
                or&nbsp;<a ui-sref='auth.login' class="show-login">login</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

here is angularjs controller code

```
'use strict';
angular.module('mean.users')
    .controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location',
        function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location) {
            $scope.user = {};

            $scope.register = function() {
                $scope.usernameError = null;
                $scope.registerError = null;
                $http.post('/register', {
                    email: $scope.user.email,
                    password: $scope.user.password,
                    confirmPassword: $scope.user.confirmPassword,
                    username: $scope.user.username,
                    name: $scope.user.name
                })
                .success(function() {
                    // authentication OK
                    $scope.registerError = 0;
                    $rootScope.user = $scope.user;
                    $rootScope.$emit('loggedin');
                    $location.url('/');
                })
                .error(function(error) {
                    // Error: authentication failed
                    if (error === 'Username already taken') {
                        $scope.usernameError = error;
                    } else if (error === 'Email already taken'){
                        $scope.emailError = error;
                    }
                    else $scope.registerError = error;
                });
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Please tell where am i doing wrong.

Comment: I faced the same problem and got it resolved by installing mean.io package through npm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved when i installed mean.io application properly on my system using node package manager. Before this, The issue was because i was using the downloaded version of github repository. Even now It is working perfect than before. I am just beginner in MEAN stack application that's why i could not identified the exact problem and posted it without clear understanding.

**Note:** Don't use downloaded version of mean.io git repository. Just download or install using Node Packege Manager(npm).

Answer (score 1):

How do you use batarang? It is a really strange tool. You have to move the pointing arrow, click on "+", select the element then, without clicking anywhere else, expand the scope values.

Another technique is, having started the dev tools (of course), right-click on the element and select "inspect element". Then in the console, you can type `angular.element($0).scope()` to get the scope of element $0 (the one you inspected).

Answer (score 0):

I found Batarang to be really clunky. Instead I now use ng-inspector (http://ng-inspector.org) which is so much more useful. It shows stuff a lot more clearly I find.

Also a great tip is to use the controller as syntax when you define your controllers by routes. It makes your controller scopes show up named in the debugger, as well as giving you lexical access to parent scopes in your templates. Super handy.

Hope that helps!